# Scaling Canvas to resize SVG in Android

Tags: android, android-canvas, svg-android

I'm not having much luck wrapping my head around this, so I'm hoping someone can help me out.

I'm getting a drawable from an SVG using svg-android, but the drawable isn't scaling to the view. Everything that I've been able to find says I should draw directly to canvas and rescale the canvas, but when I try that it only seems to change the bounds but not scale the image.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
ImageView testview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.testview);

//Get SVG and convert to drawable
SVG vector = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(),R.drawable.testvector);
Drawable test = vector.createPictureDrawable();

testview.setBackground(test);  //displays fine, but won't scale to the dimensions of
                               //the View

//function that clips the image but doesn't scale:
Drawable testTwo = new CustomPictureDrawable(vector.getPicture(), 
(float)0.5, (float)0.5);

testView.setBackground(testTwo);

class CustomPictureDrawable extends PictureDrawable {
   private float scalex, scaley;

public CustomPictureDrawable(Picture picture, float scalex, float scaley) {
    super(picture);
    this.scalex = scalex;
    this.scaley = scaley;
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    Matrix original = canvas.getMatrix();
    canvas.scale(scalex, scaley);
    super.draw(canvas);
    canvas.setMatrix(original);
}
}

//doesn't display anything
Picture testThree = vector.getPicture();

Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(10, 10, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);

c.drawPicture(testThree, new Rect(0,0,10,10));

testview.draw(c);
```

I've also found a function that will create a scaled bitmap, but the image quality is significantly reduced, so I may as well just use scaled PNGs.

Obviously I'm missing something, and my lack of experience is making it really frustrating.

What I'd *like* to be able to do is have svg-android completely re-scale the SVG before pulling a Picture or PictureDrawable out of it, but I can't figure out how to step through the SVGParser, and running multipliers on every coordinate pair would probably be super resource intensive anyway.

[edit] Is the only way to scale and re-draw the Picture and assign that to a view to create custom Views and override OnDraw?

i.e.

```
Picture testThree = vector.getPicture();

Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(10, 10, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);

c.drawPicture(testThree, new Rect(0,0,10,10));

//CustomView extends ImageView or Button or whatever with OnDraw overridden and no
//other changes 
CustomView testview = (CustomView)findViewById(R.id.testview); 

testview.OnDraw(c);
```

Am I on the right track? Canvas c would overwrite the default canvas (which is what I want), wouldn't it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out. Or at least figured out a method that works. The answer was staring me in the face in that scaled bitmap function that I didn't like. I fundamentally misunderstood how the Picture class and Draw calls work.

Code that seems to have pulled it off:

```
//Get a Picture from the SVG
SVG vector = SVGParser.getSVGfromResource(getResources(), R.raw.testvector);

Picture test = vector.getPicture();

//Redraw the picture to a new size
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(desired width, desired height, config);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

Picture resizePicture = new Picture();

canvas = resizePicture.beginRecording(desiredWidth, desiredGeight);

canvas.drawPicture(test, new Rect(0,0,desiredWidth, desiredHeight);

resizePicture.endRecording();

//get a drawable from resizePicture
Drawable vectorDrawing = new PictureDrawable(resizePicture);
```

I can size it to whatever View I want by getting desiredWidth and desiredHeight from getWidth() and getHeight() calls, and setBackground(vectorDrawing) at the end to put it on the View.

Comment: assuming your solution is in the onDraw method of your custom view, and assuming you figured out that you don't directly call that method...;-) You don't have to do anything with creating a new Canvas, or, even the bitmap. In doing that, you're losing the efficiency benefit (memory related) in using svg. Instead, you can just call canvas.drawPicture(vector.getPicture(), new Rect(0,0, width, height)), using the canvas that's passed into the onDraw method. If you want to make your view class more extendable, you can also add a style able attribute, indicating the name of the raw svg, then...

Comment: (2) and then access the resource id corresponding to the raw name with String resourceName = a.getString(R.styleable.YouViewClassName_yourViewsCustomAttributeName);

        svgResourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName, "raw", getContext().getPackageName());

Comment: Oh, and the a variable is a TypedArray object, which gives you access to all your stylable attributes you specified for your view, and is something you'll usually setup in either the constructors, or better, a simple method the constructors call. In the body of either, you'd do something like: final TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.YourCustomViewClassName, defStyle, 0);

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem and this is what I learned and how I solved it.
First I tried to render my svg directly into a canvas

```
svg.renderToCanvas(canv);
```

which didn't have the size I wanted. Then I tried to resize the image using

```
svg.renderToCanvas(canv,new RectF(0,0,200,200));
```

and

```
svg.setDocumentWidth(200);
svg.renderToCanvas(canv);
```

but both didn't work, so I started to look at my SVG. The problem was that my SVG started like this

```
<svg width="66.3679625" height="100.4148375" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

and it seems impossible, once width and height are set in the svg, to change this in code afterwards. There is also an answer in the [AndroidSvgFAQ](https://code.google.com/p/androidsvg/wiki/FAQ#My_SVG_won%27t_scale_to_fit_the_canvas_or_my_ImageView) where they recommend to remove those attributes. So I changed this to

```
 <svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1280 696" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

The viewBox attribute is the frame of my SVG picture, so if now I use the code above

```
svg.setDocumentWidth(200);
svg.renderToCanvas(canv);
```

I get the content of the box with upper left angle at (0,0) and lower right angle at (1200,696) resized such that the width is 200. You can change the behaviour for the ratio initialy it keeps ratios. Note that one can omit width, heigth and ViewBox in SVG and set the ViewBox programmatically

```
svg.setDocumentViewBox(0,0,width,height);
```

To get to know more about the ViewBox attribute see [W3ViewBox](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute).

Comment: Works like butter!